# Flutter http POST response not returning desired value

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http, flutter-getx

I've created an array of list of objects along with strings. and in my API i tried to use post method. the post method writes on the server but when i try assign the response to my List state using `Getx`. I've been using the same method for other sections and it works but when trying to do the same for this it throws an error of `[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'`. and the ui stays at loading state. only works when restarted. PLEASE what is the problem?

Client model

```
class Client {
  List<Clients>? clients;

  Client({required this.clients});

  Client.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['clients'] != null) {
      clients = <Clients>[];
      json['clients'].forEach((v) {
        clients?.add(new Clients.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.clients != null) {
      data['clients'] = this.clients!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Clients {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? address;
  String? tinNo;
  String? status;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  List<Phones>? phones;

  Clients(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.address,
      this.tinNo,
      this.status,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.phones});

  Clients.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    address = json['address'];
    tinNo = json['tin_no'];
    status = json['status'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    if (json['phones'] != null) {
      phones = <Phones>[];
      json['phones'].forEach((v) {
        phones!.add(new Phones.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    data['tin_no'] = this.tinNo;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    if (this.phones != null) {
      data['phones'] = this.phones!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Phones {
  int? id;
  String? clientId;
  Null? supplierId;
  Null? companyId;
  String? phoneNumber;
  String? email;
  String? model;
  String? category;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  Phones(
      {this.id,
      this.clientId,
      this.supplierId,
      this.companyId,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.email,
      this.model,
      this.category,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Phones.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    clientId = json['client_id'];
    supplierId = json['supplier_id'];
    companyId = json['company_id'];
    phoneNumber = json['phone_number'];
    email = json['email'];
    model = json['model'];
    category = json['category'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['client_id'] = this.clientId;
    data['supplier_id'] = this.supplierId;
    data['company_id'] = this.companyId;
    data['phone_number'] = this.phoneNumber;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

api call

```
Future createClient(String name, String address, String tin_no, String status,
    List<Phones> phones) async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}client");
  ClientController clientController = Get.put(ClientController());

  final response = await http
      .post(url,
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
            'name': name,
            'address': address,
            'tin_no': tin_no,
            'status': status,
            'phones': phones.toList()
          }))
      .then((value) {
    if (value.statusCode == 200) {
      clientController.setclientPress(true);
      clientController.createClient(Clients.fromJson(json.decode(value.body)));
      Get.back();
      clientController.setclientPress(false);
      print("success");
    } else if (value.statusCode == 500) {
      Get.snackbar("Data Exists", "The data you provided already exists.");
    } else {
      print("failed ${value.body}");
    }
    print(value.body);
  });
}
```

client controller

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:store_mgt_project/models/client/client_api.dart';
import 'package:store_mgt_project/models/client/client_model.dart';

class ClientController extends GetxController {
  final _clientPress = false.obs;
  get clientPress => _clientPress.value;
  set clientPress(value) => _clientPress.value = value;

  var allCLients = <Clients>[].obs;
  var foundClients = <Clients>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    fetchClient().then(
        (value) => {allCLients.value = value, foundClients.value = allCLients});
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {}

  void createClient(var client) {
    !allCLients.contains(client) ? allCLients.add(client) : allCLients;
    foundClients.value = allCLients.value;
    refresh();
  }

  setclientPress(bool value) {
    clientPress = value;
    update();
  }
}
```

button pressed call

```
onPressed: () async {

   List<Phones> phones = [];
   for (int i = 0; i < _groupControllers.length; i++) {
     String _phone = _groupControllers[i].phone.text;
     String _email = _groupControllers[i].email.text;
     String _category = "Reception";
     //_groupControllers[i].selectedCatagory.toString();

     setState(() {
      phones.add(Phones(
      phoneNumber: _phone,
      email: _email,
      category: _category));
     });
   }
  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      
     await createClient(
       nameController.text,
       addressController.text,
       tinController.text,
       idx.toString(),
       phones);
                      
     }
}
```

api response

```
{
    "client": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Muhammed",
        "address": "Mexico",
        "tin_no": "123456789",
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-09-09T08:44:18.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-09T08:44:18.000000Z",
        "phones": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "client_id": "1",
                "supplier_id": null,
                "company_id": null,
                "phone_number": "0911112222",
                "email": "client@com.com",
                "model": "Client",
                "category": "Sales",
                "created_at": "2022-09-09T08:44:18.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-09T08:44:18.000000Z"
            }
        ],
        "message": "Client created successfully"
    }
}
```

finally error

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
#0      new Phones.fromJson (package:store_mgt_project/models/client/client_model.dart:108:5)
#1      new Clients.fromJson.<anonymous closure> (package:store_mgt_project/models/client/client_model.dart:55:25)
#2      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:403:8)
#3      new Clients.fromJson (package:store_mgt_project/models/client/client_model.dart:54:22)
#4      createClient.<anonymous closure> (package:store_mgt_project/models/client/client_api.dart:73:28)
#5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      createClient (package:store_mgt_project/models/client/client_api.dart:54:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      _ClientBottomSheetState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:store_mgt_project/widgets/client/client_bottom_sheet.dart:500:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. I was unable to catch any discrepancies.
But as per error logs, the error is at this line.

```
category = json['category'];
```

Now, provided api response is good. But at some point `json['category']` is `int` instead of `String` or `Null`.

Please check all possible response you can think of.

Comment: actually category is not null. it returns a string. I've updated it above. but how is it returning int?